# can somone exaplin how the equations for quanterion roation actually work, or at least show me some?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I don't know enough about qunaterion rotation to as the question easily.

Sufficient to say I have a system were three rectangles on a 2 axis plan (I think those words are right.....) that are currently rotated by EUler angles.
I need them rotated by Quanterion rotation instead. Can someone explain how do that, or how that works?

Comment: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131686/rotating_objects_using_quaternions.php

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BR8tK-LuB0

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation